# Android textview: text flowing over RHS of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have created a text view (mostly auto-created by Android Studio's '**new Tabbed Activity**' helper) and populated it with some text stored as raw resources. I have allowed the view to scroll, and it's all working fine except that the last letter or two of many lines disappears off the edge of the screen. It's the same with two devices, with different screen sizes.
[image]

here's my resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.main.PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:justificationMode="inter_word"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried enlarging the marginEnd (from 20 to 50dp) - no effect, and also tried  android:gravity="center", but that made it worse!

[Edit]
As a result of suggested answers, the view has changed a little; a margin has appeared down the RHS so the text no longer disappears 'off the edge' of the screen, but it disappears 'behind' the margin. Does this help? Also , does the fact that this is a tabbed activity (as I mentioned earlier) have any bearing? If I scroll sideways, to see the next tab, the missing parts of the words still don't appear.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your TextView is not constrained to the right edge of the parents.

You can fix this by adding the following to your TextView

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

But you should avoid using left and right in your layouts. So the correct way would be to add

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

And also change `width` to `0dp` so that the TextView can take up the space defined by the constraints.

Comment: That made the LHS go missing! So I also added `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" ` and that has improved things _a little_. Text is right up against the edge of the screen though, there are no margins shown at all.

Comment: No change, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` on your textView with start and end constraint set to parent.

Comment: Still no real difference. I have added some more info; see my recent edit